# Remove the last element inside an array

Tags: c, arrays

My problem: I do not know how to delete the last element entered inside the array. The program should stop when the user enters a negative number and should not include the negative number inside the array. I tried, but I cant find the solution. This is my Code:

```
int main () {
 float array[20];
 float max ,min;
 float rem;
 int i;
 char op;
 for (i = 0; i <= 20; i++){
        printf("Enter the element inside array[%d]: ",i);
        scanf("%f", &array[i]);
        if (array[i] < 0)
            break;
}
printf("Enter ......: ");
scanf("%s", &op);

switch (op){
    case 'h':
        max = array[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            if (max < array[i]){
                max = array[i];

            }
        }
        printf("The biggest number is: %f\n", max);
        break;

    case 'l':
        min = array[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            if (min > array[i]){
                    min = array[i];

            }
        }
        printf("The smallest number is: %f\n", min);
        break;


}


return 0;
}
```

Please help , I run out of ideas.
Thank you very much.

Comment: This isn't C# - it looks like it's just C.

Comment: In C, it is up to you to keep track of how many elements are actually in use in array or other buffer. So, keep track of that, and then "deleting" last item is simply matter of decreasing your own length variable by one. There is no other mechanism is C.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check entered value before storing in array:

```
int main () {
 float array[20]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
 float max ,min;
 float rem;
 int i;
 float a;
 char op;
 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("Enter the element inside array[%d]: ",i);
        scanf("%f", &a);
        if (a < 0)
            break;
        array[i]=a;
}
```

Comment: Still doesnt work.
When i break it and enter h it gives me a really long number (incorrect number)
When I enter 'l' then it give me 0.000, even tho i never entered 0.0 as an element of array.

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary variable before , if it is positive store in array , if not take necessary actions.

```
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    printf("Enter the element inside array[%d]: ",i);
    scanf("%f", &x)        // declare x as float x;
    if (x< 0)              // if negative break
        break;
      array[i]=x;            // store into array
 }
```

**And also some problems in your program** -

```
printf("Enter ......: ");
scanf("%s", &op);     // op is char variable use %c specifier      
       ^ use instead %c
```

Write like this instead-

```
scanf(" %c", &op);
```

this first loop access index out of bound causing **UB**

```
for (i = 0;i<=20; i++){    // change condition to i<20 (index can go from 0 to 19)
   //your code               // as array is declared as float array[20]           
}
```

**Both the loops for `max` and `min` can go like this** -

```
 for (i= 0;array[i]; i++){            // no need to keep track of length of array
```

[Click on link to see working code.](https://ideone.com/TOrUVk)

Comment: It breaks when i enter a negative number, but when i enter 'l' it shows me that the smallest number is the negative number that i entered

Comment: @question  Yes that's why use a temporary variable , so if it is negative it will directly come out of loop , without storing in array .  Also don't forget to make changes as your code has _undefined behaviour_ .

Comment: But it should show the smallest number without the negative number.
Ex: {1,2,3,4,-5}

smallest number: 1 not -5

Comment: @question A negative number will not be stored when you try ameyCU's solution.

Comment: @ameyCU [This issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933042/remove-the-last-element-inside-an-array#comment53691874_32933096) will arise when using your solution.

Comment: @CoolGuy  Yes, I was looking at it .After changes I made , it gave me seg fault.

Comment: @question  Please take a look . Now that problem has been solved.

Comment: I changed everything you suggested me. One problem when I enter 20 elements and want to find out what the biggest number is, then it wont let me enter the char op.

Comment: @question  If you made all corrections , then wont get any problem . I don't get any problem . taking `op` in `scanf ` make sure you leave a space before `%c` .

Comment: @question Check the link again. There program takes `20` numbers as input and gives biggest . Program works fine .

Answer (score 1):

**i am sorry for my last answer but this is true ;)**

```
#include<stdio.h>


int length(const float *array) {
  int count = 0;
  while(array[count]) count++;
  return count;
}


void main () {
 float array[20];
 float max ,min;
 float rem,input;
 int i;
 char op;
 int length = 0;
 for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        printf("Enter the element inside array[%d]: ",i);
        scanf("%f", &input);
        if (input < 0)
            break;
        length++;
        array[i] = input;
}

printf("Enter ......: ");
scanf(" %c", &op);

switch (op){
    case 'h':
        max = array[0];
        for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            if (max < array[i]){
                max = array[i];

            }
        }
        printf("The biggest number is: %f\n", max);
        break;

    case 'l':
        min = array[0];
        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i){
            if (min > array[i]){
                    min = array[i];

            }
        }
        printf("The smallest number is: %f\n", min);
        break;


}

system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You've posted several answers that are just a code dump with no explanation for the problem or how you fixed it. These aren't very good answers, you are forcing readers to search and compare to find what changed. Can you please add some explanation text in the future?

Comment: I am new in stackoverflow. Thanks for advice. I will add more explanation in the future.